# Copy elements from an array to an array list but skip element if some elements have been previously entered

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to loop through the array below and then add elements from it to an array list using the format below.

This is the array:

```
    String[] arr = {
            "room1", "10.11.2017", "17:00-18:00", "meeting event",
            "room2", "12.11.2017", "19:00-20:00", "meeting event",
            "room3", "20.11.2017", "20:00:21:00", "meeting event",
            "room1", "10.11.2017", "18:00-19:00", "meeting event",
            "room1", "15.11.2017", "10:00-11:00", "meeting event",
            "room2", "12.11.2017", "21:00-22:00", "meeting event",
            "room2", "12.11.2017", "22:00-23:00", "meeting event",
            "room3", "20.11.2017", "21:00:22:00", "meeting event",
            "room1", "10.11.2017", "19:00-20:00", "meeting event",
            "room4", "30.11.2017", "09:00-10:00", "meeting event"
    };
```

I would like to get a new array list containing the following string elements:

```
room1 , 10.11.2017 , 17:00-18:00 , 18:00-19:00 , 19:00-20:00 , meeting event
room2 , 12.11.2017 , 19:00-20:00 , 21:00-22:00 , 22:00-23:00 , meeting event
room3 , 20.11.2017 , 20:00:21:00 , 21:00:22:00 , meeting event
room1 , 15.11.2017 , 10:00-11:00 , meeting event
room4 , 30.11.2017 , 09:00-10:00 , meeting event
```

But instead I get:

```
room1 , 10.11.2017 , 17:00-18:00 , 18:00-19:00 , 19:00-20:00 , meeting event
room2 , 12.11.2017 , 19:00-20:00 , 21:00-22:00 , 22:00-23:00 , meeting event
room3 , 20.11.2017 , 20:00:21:00 , 21:00:22:00 , meeting event
room1 , 10.11.2017 , 18:00-19:00 , 19:00-20:00 , meeting event
room1 , 15.11.2017 , 10:00-11:00 , meeting event
room2 , 12.11.2017 , 21:00-22:00 , 22:00-23:00 , meeting event
room2 , 12.11.2017 , 22:00-23:00 , meeting event
room3 , 20.11.2017 , 21:00:22:00 , meeting event
room1 , 10.11.2017 , 19:00-20:00 , meeting event
room4 , 30.11.2017 , 09:00-10:00 , meeting event
```

Is there a way to change the code below such that to get the result I need?

```
ArrayList<String> arr2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    String roomNumber= new String();
    String bookedDate = new String();
    String bookedTime = new String();
    String event = new String();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=4) {
        roomNumber = arr[i];
        bookedDate = arr[i+1];
        bookedTime = arr[i+2];
        event = arr[i+3];

        for (int j = i + 4; j < arr.length; j+=4) {
                if (arr[i].equals(arr[j]) && arr[i+1].equals(arr[j+1]) && !arr[i+2].equals(arr[j+2])){
                    bookedTime = bookedTime + " , " + arr[j+2];
                } 
            }

        arr2.add(roomNumber +  " , " + bookedDate + " , " + bookedTime +  " , " + event);
        }

    for (int k =  0; k <arr2.size(); k++) {
        System.out.println(arr2.get(k));
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know what you're working on, but maybe creating a model to hold that information would be better than using Strings entirely. Also, an arraylist has a .contains method i.e. arr2.contain("string") that returns a boolean value. You should try  that as well

Comment: The string elements are taken from a txt file. All I need is to get the array elements in that order. Im wondering if there’s a way to do that using the array and array list. I’m new to Java and I’m not sure what your suggestion means.

Comment: Is there a structure in the text file? As in is the information properly ordered?

Comment: The information is exactly like that from the array. But let's say I only have that array and forget about the txt file. Is there a way to loop through it and copy the elements in that order? My code partially achieves what I need  but it includes duplicates than I need because of looping the entire array.

Comment: @OctavianBordeanu Java is an OO language. Define and use classes, with named and typed properties. Your array of string should be a List<RoomReservation>, where a RoomReservation has a String roomName, a LocalDate day, a LocalTime startTime and a LocalTime endTime, and an eventType. Manipulating sub arrays makes the code very hard to grasp, and thus implement.

Comment: @JBNizet good point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As https://stackoverflow.com/users/2369963/adamson-jeremiah posted, the best way to solve this problem is by using classes and objects. But if you are looking to modify your existing code, the problem is that you are trying to compare records which are already checked. We can use a boolean array to not compare records which are already compared. A record in this case is a combination of 4 array elements.

```
import java.util.*;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   String[] arr = {
            "room1", "10.11.2017", "17:00-18:00", "meeting event",
            "room2", "12.11.2017", "19:00-20:00", "meeting event",
            "room3", "20.11.2017", "20:00:21:00", "meeting event",
            "room1", "10.11.2017", "18:00-19:00", "meeting event",
            "room1", "15.11.2017", "10:00-11:00", "meeting event",
            "room2", "12.11.2017", "21:00-22:00", "meeting event",
            "room2", "12.11.2017", "22:00-23:00", "meeting event",
            "room3", "20.11.2017", "21:00:22:00", "meeting event",
            "room1", "10.11.2017", "19:00-20:00", "meeting event",
            "room4", "30.11.2017", "09:00-10:00", "meeting event"
    };

ArrayList<String> arr2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    String roomNumber= new String();
    String bookedDate = new String();
    String bookedTime = new String();
    String event = new String();
    // array to check if record is already checked. 
    boolean[] alreadyChecked = new boolean[arr.length/4];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=4) {
        roomNumber = arr[i];
        bookedDate = arr[i+1];
        bookedTime = arr[i+2];
        event = arr[i+3];
        // If record is already checked, continue
        if(alreadyChecked[i/4] == true)
          continue;

        for (int j = i + 4; j < arr.length; j+=4) {
                if (arr[i].equals(arr[j]) && arr[i+1].equals(arr[j+1]) && !arr[i+2].equals(arr[j+2]) && alreadyChecked[j/4] == false){
                    bookedTime = bookedTime + " , " + arr[j+2];
                    // Mark the record as checked
                    alreadyChecked[j/4] = true;
                } 
            }

        arr2.add(roomNumber +  " , " + bookedDate + " , " + bookedTime +  " , " + event);
        // mark the record as checked
        alreadyChecked[i/4] = true;
        }

    for (int k =  0; k <arr2.size(); k++) {
        System.out.println(arr2.get(k));
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

An object-oriented approach would serve you better in the long run. Before I try to mock-up a possible solution, I'd like to point out the following:

1. Your original array, arr containing Strings is actually just one large array. It looks structured in lines, but it really has no structure in reality. This questions why you would use an array to fetch your data from the file.

In my opinion, a model class or classes representing your entire system would be better. Just as an example, you could have a class like this:

```
public class HotelRoom {
   private String roomId;
   private String roomType;
}

public class Booking {
   private HotelRoom room;
   private String purpose;
   private Date bookingDate;
}
```

These models are not complete, but they paint a picture of what I mean. So booking information might be what is contained in your file, hence you could create your models as you read from the file, create these objects, then put it in the array list. That kind of structure helps. You can ask questions where you need clarity. Enjoy

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a try.